# 2 columns collapses after changing div height dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry but this can be a really basic question.

I have a lot of divs one next to each other aligned with float right and left. At the start there is a fixed max-height and width in each div, so the divs are aligned ok.

But when I try to change the height dynamically with javascript, the container collapses and it doesn't respect the float anymore.

I made an example so you can see it, it's not my real code but it's showing the problem also:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.post').each(function() {
  $(this).css({
   'max-height': 160,
   'overflow': 'hidden',
  });
 });
 $('.post').click(function() {
  $(this).css({
   'max-height': 'none',
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.clear:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
.post {
  width: 50%;
}
.post div {
  background: #FFFFE4;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 30px;
}
.post:nth-child(odd)  {
 float: left;
}
.post:nth-child(even)  {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container clear">

 <div class="post">
  <div>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="post">
  <div>
   Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="post">
  <div>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="post">
  <div>
   At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

As you can see, some divs floated right go to left or viceversa.

How to keep the order horizontally and vertically after changing height?

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot see the full text? I cannot understand very well what is exactly your question. When I execute the script that you put, it works fine for me (I mean, they are displayed both horizontally and vertically in a good order).

Comment: @Error404 The problem is when clicking a div, so the height can change with jquery. Well the height doesn't change actually, just override the max-height

Comment: after each two divs (a row) you need something called "clearfix" - try that.

Comment: @JoseCarlosRamírez Oh sorry, I did not see that you had a click event on your Javascript. Then @PeterB answer is the correct. You should use `clear` to determine that some specific element do not inherit float property from its parents.

Comment: @Airrudi had it, there is a snippet here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36947934/6265633

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to create a two column layout, you could create two additional divs (left and right) inside the container div. For example:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div class="post"></div>
        <div class="post"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <div class="post"></div>
        <div class="post"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will prevent the entire row from getting the same height as the expanded post and will only push down the posts in the same column.

Comment: I'm going to mark this because its simplicity. Not what I was looking for in the beginning (wrap all  the divs in the same container), but it's working really well too. And it's a good way to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `<div class="container clear">` for every two `post` divs, instead of putting it all in one big div.

This will push all content down on expand, instead of push down one 'column' (in case that is what you wanted...).

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/37ndqrd2/

Comment: Though this doesn't wrap divs together (vertically) when div left is higher than div right, it's nice to see how `clear` works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following are the changes:

- Removed all floats and clear. I've been a web developer for a while and I still don't get how floats work. They are fragile and old antiques.
- Wrapped the both pairs of `.post` in a section that has `display: flex` and [`justify-content: space-around`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/)
- Made your jQuery to toggle between class using [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

  - `.compressed { max-height: 160px; overflow: hidden;}`
  - `.expanded { min-height: 160px; overflow: auto; }`

### SNIPPET

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.post').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded compressed');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.col {
  width: 50%;
}
.post div {
  background: #FFFFE4;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 30px;
}
.expanded {
  min-height: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.compressed {
  max-height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container clear">
  <section class="col left">
    <div class="post compressed">
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="post compressed">
      <div>
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
        sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
        incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea
        voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="col right">
    <div class="post compressed">
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="post compressed">
      <div>
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
        animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
        est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
        voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For everybody looking for the same question:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.post  div').each(function() {
  $(this).css({
   'max-height': '110px',
   'overflow': 'hidden',
  });
 });
 $('.post > div').click(function() {
  $(this).css({
   'max-height': 'none',
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.clear:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
.column {
 width: 50%;
}
.left {
 float: left;
}
.right {
 float: right;
}
.post {
 width: 100%;
}
.post div {
 background: #FFFFE4;
 padding: 15px;
 margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container clear">

    <div class="column right">
  <div class="post">
   <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
   <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   </div>
  </div>
    </div>
 
 <div class="column left">
  <div class="post">
   <div>
                Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
   <div>
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
   </div>
  </div>
    </div>
 
</div>
```